# Connect Python saas to datadog for logging report purposes

Tags: python, datadog

I am trying to connect my python system to datadog. I have installed the AGENT on my pc and it is running. The dataDog report all the activities of the pc, cpu, disk, io, memory and network.  I am now wanting to report the activities on my python system

Comment: You have to install the Dogstatsd client and initialize it according to the [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/?tab=hostagent#install-the-dogstatsd-client). Then you can start sending [metrics](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/dogstatsd_metrics_submission/).

Comment: [This](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/python/?tab=containers) is what I am following

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: What do I need to do to have the `datadog.yaml` in my system?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.